# Button didn't redirect to other page

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Im writting a code for my assigment "So,im now at view  profile page when i click the button it will redirect to the update profile page when I hover the button the url is right but the button still stay at the same page" This is my code

```
    <div class="btn-block">
      <button type="button" value="back" onclick="location.href='homepage.html'">Back</button>
      <?php 
      echo '<a href="updateprofile.php?editid='.$edit_id.'" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><button>Apply</button></a>'
      
    ?>
      </div>
```

I home somebody could fix this

Comment: Why don't you use anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

It is improper to nest `a` and `button` inside either the same or the other element. You could likely achieve a better result by using CSS to style the `a` instead of relying on JavaScript to make a link from the buttons.

```
<button type="button" value="back" onclick="location.href='updateprofile.php?editid=<?= $edit_id ?>'">Apply</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `javascript:` before your javascript in the `onclick` attribute like the following.

```
<button type="button" value="back" onclick="javascript:location.href='homepage.html'">Back</button>
```

See Codepen to see this working.
https://codepen.io/hiroshisan/pen/ZEqjbyQ

```
<div class="btn-block">
  <button type="button" value="back" onclick="javascript:location.href='homepage.html'">Back</button>
  <?php echo '<a href="updateprofile.php?editid='.$edit_id.'" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><button>Apply</button></a>' ?>
</div>
```